# VBA Copy and pastevalues in another sheet using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an excel with a macro which does this:
It takes a values from one sheet and paste them in another sheet in the first empty Row. I currently have this and this does paste but then the formula, not the values. When I change Paste to Pastespecial it does not work anymore. Can anybody help me with this?

```
Sub CopyPasteSpecial()
Set wsA = Sheet3
Set wsW = Sheet5
wsA.Range("A3").Copy


Sheet5.Activate
  Dim i As Integer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  NumRows = Range("C5", Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Range("C5").Select
  For i = 1 To NumRows
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this below code for **pasting as values** & **no need to iterate to get to the last empty row** as well...

```
Sub CopyPasteSpecial()
Set wsA = Sheet3
Set wsW = Sheet5
wsA.Range("A3").Copy

Sheet5.Activate
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
NumRows = Range("C5", Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("C" & NumRows + 5).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
 
End Sub
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you very much! It does indeed work, great idea. This help me very much

Answer (score 1):

The (accepted) answer of Sachin Kohli contains so many problems that it is too much to write in a comment. All of them causes errors that can be found thousend times on Stackoverflow.

**(a)** Don´t use `Select` and `Activate` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/7599798  - You have already a worksheet variable to sheet5 (`wsW`), so use it.
**(b)** Copying data (values) between ranges (=cells) can be done without Copy&Paste. This is much faster.
**(c)** When dealing with row and column numbers, use datatype `Long`, else you risk an overflow error in large sheets. Basically, use *always* `Long` instead of `Integer` - the data type Integer exists only for historic reasons.
**(d)** *Always* put **Optiona Explicit** at the top of your code and declare all variables. This will save you a lot of headaches because typos in variable names will be caught by the compiler.

```
Sub CopyPasteSpecial()
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsW As Worksheet
    Set wsW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsA = Sheet1
    Set wsW = Sheet2

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsW.Cells(wsW.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    wsW.Cells(lastRow + 1, "C").Value = wsA.Range("A3").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues in your answer @funthomas... & to be honest, I was aware of all these points which you mentioned in your detailed answer, however I just focused on tweaking the code for only the part where OP was struggling...